# XmlPullParser exception - can't work it out

Tags: android, xmlpullparser

I have a basic method - ReadXML() - that reads in an xml file from the assets folder. When this runs no exceptions are thrown. But from within this method I call a doXML() method that tries to extract text from the xml file and set this text into textviews. I keep getting the following error when the doXML() method runs...The error that is generated is

```
18:19:41.654: W/System.err(329): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: name expected (position:START_TAG @59:57 in java.io.InputStreamReader@44f049c8).
```

I tried to shorten the xml file to see where the error is...essentially if there are four "trials" each with a title, author, etc. the first three will actually load into the textviews...although the above error is still generated in LogCat...but the last one won't load...so there's probably an issue with the code logic but can't figure it out.

thanks in advance.

```
<trial>
<title>The Book</title>
<author></author>
....
</trial>
```

I think the code is probably more complicated than it needs to be...but can't figure out why the doXML() method won't run properly.

```
public void ReadXML() throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
   {

      factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
      factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
      xpp = factory.newPullParser();

      InputStream raw = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("trial_info.xml");
      xpp.setInput(raw,null);
   }
}


public void doXML() throws  XmlPullParserException, IOException{


          int eventType = XmlPullParser.START_TAG;

          while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
          {
            if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT && xpp.getText().equals(selectedTrial))
              {
                   trialTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TrialAbbrevData);
                   trialTxt.setText(xpp.getText());
                   Log.d("what is this", xpp.getText());

           while(!(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equals("...")))
                   {  

          if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && xpp.getName().equals("trialName"))
                      {    
                         eventType = xpp.next();
                         if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT)
                         {
                            trialTxtDesc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TrialNameData);
                            trialTxtDesc.setText(xpp.getText());
                            Log.d("in loop",xpp.getText());
                         }
                      }

       if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && xpp.getName().equals("trialDetails"))
                      {   
                         eventType = xpp.next();
                         if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT)
                         {
                            trialTxtConc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TrialDescData);
                            trialTxtConc.setText(xpp.getText());
                         }
                      }

       if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && xpp.getName().equals("trialResults"))
                      {   
                         eventType = xpp.next();
                         if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT)
                         {
                     trialTxtConc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TrialResultsData);
                            trialTxtConc.setText(xpp.getText());
                         }
                      }

   if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && xpp.getName().equals("trialConclusion"))
                      {   
                         eventType = xpp.next();
                         if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT)
                         {
                            trialTxtConc=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TrialConclusionData);
                            trialTxtConc.setText(xpp.getText());
                         }
                      }

        if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && xpp.getName().equals("whatItMeans"))
                      {  
                          eventType = xpp.next();
                          if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT)
                          {
                             trialTxtMeans = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TrialWIMData);
                             trialTxtMeans.setText(xpp.getText());
                          }
                      }

                      eventType = xpp.next();

                   }         



            }
              eventType = xpp.next();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the XML that is failing?